# trouble showing hidden div with onchange function in javascript/html select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble showing and hiding a div in html/javascript.

```
<html>

<body>
    <form name="saleproperty" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return CommonFunction(this);">
        <select id='rentsalelease'> 
     <option value="RENT">RENT</option> 
     <option value="SALE">SALE</option> 
     <option value="LEASE">LEASE</option>
    </select>
        <div style='display:none;' id='salevalue'>Sale Value<br/>
            <input type='text' name='business' size='20' />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rentsalelease').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value == 'SALE') {
            $("#salevalue").show();
        } else {
            $("#salevalue").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I want to show the div after selecting the option with the value of "SALE".
The hidden div is not showing when changing option value of the select to "SALE".

Comment: have you added the refrence to jQuery library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 i just added ajax library url to your code

<html> 
<body>  
<form name="saleproperty" action="" method="POST"
onsubmit="return CommonFunction(this);" > 
<select id='rentsalelease'> 
 <option value="RENT">RENT</option> 
 <option value="SALE">SALE</option> 
 <option value="LEASE">LEASE</option>
</select> 
<div style='display:none;' id='salevalue'>Sale Value<br/>
   <input type='text' name='business'  size='20' />
 </div> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rentsalelease').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'SALE')
      //.....................^.......
      {
        $("#salevalue").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#salevalue").hide();
      }
    });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: it is better to describe what th issue ios and what you have changed to fix the problem than simply posting the code which may or may not be obvious as to what was changed.

Comment: @Sanjay Kumar 22 i just added jquery ajax library url to your code.

Comment: yes it is after adding ajax library its working ,but is it compulasory to add ajax library ? i am very new to jquery

Comment: is there any option without adding ajax library url

Comment: @SanjayKumar22 yes, jquery won't work without including it's library read some tutorials on jquery

Comment: @SanjayKumar22 yes, you can copy that code to new file and save that file to your folder and load that jquery file wherever required .make sure jquery library path is correct whenever using jquery in your page..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code didn't work but you can achieve the same result using `change` function like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#rentsalelease').change(function() {
     if (this.value == 'SALE') {
       $("#salevalue").show();
     } else {
       $("#salevalue").hide();
     }
   });
});
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjqkvpnh/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: isn't .change() simply a shorthand way of saying .on('change',...)?